# MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver returns wrong datatype to ADODB

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc, type-conversion

Situation: working with legacy classic ASP code, attempting to move the codebase from an old server to a new one.

The code attempts to connect to a MySQL database on a Windows server using the MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver and the ADODB.Connection object.

```
Connection String = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=dbserver;Database=dbname;Uid=username;Password=password;Option=3"
```

Query results are returned in ADODB.RecordSet objects.
When I try to access a field containing a standard MySQL Integer, I get this error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ca'
>   Variable uses an Automation type not supported in VBScript

If I manually convert the field using cLng() then the error is eliminated and the correct value is returned.  However, there is too much code to manually look for each reference to an integer and manually convert it.

VarType() returns 19 for these values, which appears to be some type of Long datatype that VB doesn't understand. ([See here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/general/21478-vartype-19-a.html))
Isn't the ODBC driver supposed to return VarType 3 for long integers? ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/3kfz157h(v=vs.84).aspx))

I tried passing the option 16384 (NO_BIGINT) in the "option=" parameter of the connection string but it didn't make any difference.

Any idea how to correct this? It seems there should be an option to pass to the MySQL ODBC driver to return longs as Long Integer datatype, but I can't find it.

Before anyone mentions it: yes we know classic ASP is bad.  No we don't have the resources to port this code to something else right now. We just need it to continue working on classic ASP for the current time.

Comment: Don't let anyone tell you that classic ASP is somehow intrinsically bad. (I've never worked with MySQL, so can't help with your actual question, but I wanted to put this out there.)

Comment: @Martha they don't need to be writing that, Classic ASP isn't bad it's just old. Still have lots of projects that have to be supported that won't move over to .Net. A lot of the time the client is happy how it performs so it stays put.

Comment: Can you upgrade the driver to version 5.3 and check?

Comment: what's the dataype of the column? INT, BIGINT? Is column ZEROFILL nor UNSIGNED? what's the architecture 32-bit or 64-bit? And what are the values of `Connection.Properties("DBMS Version")`, `Connection.Properties("Driver Version")` and `Connection.Properties("Provider Version")`. Answering these questions would be helpful to figure the problem out. @Lankymart the downvote mafia is getting famous day by day :)

Comment: @SearchAndResQ I don't have access to the host server to upgrade the driver, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin the column is unsigned int(10).  Host is Windows 2012 (probably 64-bit).  DBMS Version: 5.6.26-log, Driver Version: 05.01.0009, Provider Version: 06.03.9600.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK by the process of elimination I finally discovered the problem.  Not sure *why* this occurs but it must be a bug in the MySQL ODBC driver.

Integer fields having the UNSIGNED attribute cause the error.  Removing this attribute causes the field value to be returned as a standard Integer type.  Apparently the ODBC driver is not handling the conversion from unsigned int to vbscript Integer type properly, and is instead returning a pointer to a Long.

I also noticed this problem on tinyint(1) fields which I was using as boolean values.  Changing the datatype from tinyint(1) to int(11) [the default] eliminated this error also.

Hopefully this will help someone else.  FYI I also posted this issue in the MySQL ODBC Driver forum but nobody bothered to respond.