# JScript Number() function returns nothing but "[object] is not a number"

Tags: asp-classic, ado, iis-8, jscript

I am using JScript in Classic ASP, IIS 8.0, to retrieve a numerical value from a MySQL 5.5-database generated ADO RecordSet to use as a number.  The recordset is fine, and the value returns, visually, accurate, however, casting the object to a Number to use numerically produces the following error in the IIS logs:

> "[object] is not number"

Code:

```
var total = Number(rs("kount"));
```

When trying to trace the issue I see the proper results:

```
Response.Write(typeof rs("kount")); // RETURNS "object"
Response.Write(rs("kount"));        // RETURNS 1
```

If Number() fails, and parseInt(rs("kount"), 10); also fails (I tried that, also produced "[object] is not a number", and all other recordset variations (rs.Fields(1), rs.Fields.Item(1)) all fail in the exact same way, how then do I convert the Object rs("kount") into the Number 1, or whatever Number it's supposed to be?

Comment: The `Number()` constructor itself will not produce that error.

Comment: Well, it's an object, and in some cases it gives you the default property it has (value).  However you are still passing an object to Number,  Try rs.Fields("kount").Value

Comment: `Number({ foo: "bar" })` returns `NaN`.

Comment: I got "Object does not support this property or method" on rs.Fields("kount").Value

Comment: NaN is not returned; nothing is returned

Comment: Maybe rs.Fields.Item("kount").Value

Comment: That too, James.  Tried every known combination via W3Schools, ASPTutorials, you name it.  But yes, rs.Fields.Item("kount").Value choked too; "Object does not support this property or method"

Comment: *"I am using Javascript in Classic ASP"* - You can use JScript in Classic ASP, not JavaScript, do not confuse the two.

Comment: Debug this in Visual studio and inspect the type which rs("kount") is. Sounds like a recordset reader error to me.

Comment: rs("kount") type is "object" when viewed comes back as.. 1

Comment: Try casting it to string first then `parseInt()` it. Something like `var total = parseInt(rs("kount") + "");`.

Comment: parseInt() failed too in the exact same way, even if cast as String; it produced [object] is not a String if cast into String, otherwise, [object] is not a number

Comment: What type of number field are you using in the MySQL table?

Comment: int(11) for MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 8

Comment: Could [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37200105/692942) to be related?

Comment: According to [an answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63757282/1682881), you must have tried `rs("kount").Item` ?

Comment: I did, and rs("kount").Item also returned "Object does not support this property or method"

Answer (score 1):

@Lankymart was on the money with this one!!

Turns out that when you did the original query that I did for returning the values along with the total, using `count(*) as kount` failed, because count(*) returns a LONG, not an integer, and, because of that, both Number() and String() functions choke on it.

When I did this instead `CAST(count(*) as CHAR(32))`, then it worked; it cast the int(11) into char(32), which Number() [and String()] recognize and can convert into a Number, thus, the problem was completely resolved.

Thanks all!

Comment: Glad that worked for you.